# ubuntu (or Glovebox) like sidebar in android

Tags: android

Glovebox popsup one sidebar (concept taken from Ubuntu OS)at the left edge of the screen. What UI component should I use to replicate the same feature inside my application.

Answer (score -1):

There is the ActionBar which can contain custom items with custom icons. though its meant to be on top (expanding on bottom too), and not on right or left side..

..OR..

..you can have a look on Drawers, which you can find [HERE.](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)
There are several different types of drawers, maybe the navigation-drawer suits your expectations.